# Java Spring - Repositório retorna Null

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository

Esta é minha classe ApiKey:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="API_KEYS", schema="DEMO_PIMS")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(allowGetters=true)
public class ApiKey implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_REG")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="SERVICE")
    private String service;

    @Column(name="KEY")
    private String Key;
(... Getters and Setters...)
```

Este é o repositório:

```
 @Repository
public interface ApiKeyRepository extends JpaRepository<ApiKey, Integer>{   

    @Query("SELECT a FROM ApiKey a WHERE a.service = ?1")
    ApiKey getByservice(String nome);

}
```

Estou usando a classe ClimaTempoAPI.java que possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
  public class ClimaTempoAPI {

    @Autowired
    ApiKeyRepository apiKeyRepository;

    public JSONObject RequestWeather(String weatherEndpoint) throws IOException, JSONException, ParseException {


        ApiKey appToken = apiKeyRepository.getByservice("climaTempo2");


        URL weatherDomain = new URL("http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br" + weatherEndpoint + appToken.getKey());

        return ConnectionJson.returnJson(weatherDomain, true);

    }

}
```

Mas ao chamar o método getByservice("climaTempo2") ele lança uma exceção de Null Pointer Exception.

O que estou fazendo de errado que não faz funcionar?

Já vi outras respostas no StackOverflow, mas o que eles colocaram como solução não funcionou para mim:

[StackOverflow em inglês - Testei adicionando o @Service, @Configurable e @Component - Não deu certo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

[StackOverflow em inglês - @Service, @Transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811276/spring-jpa-repository-findone-return-null)

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

Comment: Seria interessante você citar quais soluções já tentou e não funcionaram.

Comment: Outra coisa: a classe que contém o método `main` (onde você provavelmente usou a anotação `@SpringBootApplication`) da sua aplicação está num pacote acima de todos os demais?

Comment: ClimaTempoAPI não teria um @Service? Onde você diz que ClimaTempoAPI  é gerenciada pelo spring para fazer a injeção de dependência?

Comment: @StatelessDev quanto ao main já está dessa maneira que vc disse. No código eu não coloquei, mas já tentei usando as anotações @ Service, @ Component e dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: `@Service`, `@Component` e `@Repository` cumprem a mesma função (fazer da classe um _bean_ a ser descoberto pelo _autoscan_ do Spring). Sua anotação aí está correta.

Comment: Não sei se isso seria um problema: A classe ClimaTempoAPI.java está num pacote acima que o do controller que chama ela...

Comment: Você pode postar a estrutura de pacotes da sua aplicação?

Comment: Sim, atualizei na pergunta

Comment: `APILux` é onde está seu `main`?

Comment: Exatamente... O resto do projeto funciona normalmente (mas nas outras APIs não estou usando o ApiKeyRepository)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79448/discussion-between-statelessdev-and-witnesstruth).

Comment: Qual classe usa `ClimaTempoAPI`? Coloque ela na pergunta. Compartilhe também **todo** o erro do NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei o porque, mas só resolveu quando eu passei o código para a classe do ClimaTempoController.

ClimaTempoController.java:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/cockpit")
    @CrossOrigin(origins="*", maxAge=3600)
    public class ClimaTempoController { 

        @Autowired
        ApiKeyRepository apiKeyRepository;  

        @RequestMapping(value= "/clima/{nomeCidade}/{ufCidade}/agora",  method = {RequestMethod.GET})
        public ResponseEntity<Clima> getClimaAgoraByNomeCidade(@PathVariable etc etc..) {
            (...)
            ApiKey appToken = apiKeyRepository.getByservice("climaTempo2");
            climaCidade = ct.RequestWeather(weatherEndpoint, appToken.getKey());

        }
     }
```

O mesmo código só que em uma classe @RestController